# SPFx event to fire when layout is changed

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have created a web-part in SPFx. I am trying to run some code when the layout is changed from single column to double column layout.

`this.domElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;`

I tried this line of code but it gets the page width not the width of SPFx layout area.

Is there any event available which fires when we change the layout?

Comment: Did your tried to follow [this](https://www.netwoven.com/2018/11/13/resizing-of-spfx-react-web-parts-in-different-scenarios/)?

Comment: yes, this gives us the layout size. but only when page is refreshed. can we fire this event the moment layout is changed by the user?

Comment: Does is it also change after page is republished??